# Differences between these arrays and how can I compare them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, compare

I have two arrays, one looks like:

```
["ssewweewewzad0xsis", "sasasaasasaas", "ddwdwd", "ffdfdfdffdfdf", "rffrfrfrfrfrrf", "rffrfrfrffrfrfrfbyzad0xsis
", "dsdssddssd", "ssdsddssd"]
```

The other looks like:

```
[
Array[8]
0: "ssdsddssd"
1: "dsdssddssd"
2: "rffrfrfrffrfrfrfbyzad0xsis↵"
3: "rffrfrfrfrfrrf"
4: "ffdfdfdffdfdf"
5: "ddwdwd"
6: "sasasaasasaas"
7: "ssewweewewzad0xsis"
length: 8
__proto__: Array[0]
```

(taken from the Developer Console in Chrome)

What are the differences between them and how can I check if they're the same?

The first one is from a parsed JSON, the second one is `var array = new Array();` and its values are added through `array.push()`.

Comment: Is the second an array in an array? Does it show up as `[ Array[8] ]`?

Comment: it shows up in the developer tools as http://p.fr.am/AXRu but I started learning jQuery a little time ago and I don't know exactly what is it

Comment: please post the code that copies from one to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot it appears that is an array inside an array.

To get the nested array, you can use `theArray[0]`.

For example:

```
var arr  = [1, 2, 3], // shows up as [1, 2, 3]
    arr2 = [arr];     // shows up as [ Array[3] ] which you can expand
                      // with the arrow
```

Then:

```
arr2[0] === arr;
```

To compare, it depends on whether the arrays reference to the same thing.

If so, use `arr2[0] === arr`.

Otherwise, you can use one of the algorithms available on the internet. In Chrome, it's possible to do this as well:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3],
    b = [1, 2, 3];

a === b;          // false
a <= b && a >= b; // true
```

Answer (score 1):

First check if both the arrays are of the same length. Then itertate through both and check if all the corresponding values are strictly equal (===).

Comment: @Pointy a more fundamental question is _why_ is the second instance reversed?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a loop you can use join to compare the strings.

```
function checkArrays( arrA, arrB ){

    //check if lengths are different
    if(arrA.length !== arrB.length) return false;


    //slice so we do not effect the orginal
    //sort makes sure they are in order
    //join makes it a string so we can do a string compare
    var cA = arrA.slice().sort().join(""); 
    var cB = arrB.slice().sort().join("");

    return cA===cB;

}

var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
var b = [5,4,3,2,1];
var c = [1,2,3,4];
var d = [1,2,3,4,6];
var e = ["1","2","3","4","5"];  //will return true

console.log( checkArrays(a,b) );  //true
console.log( checkArrays(a,c) );  //false
console.log( checkArrays(a,d) );  //false
console.log( checkArrays(a,e) );  //true
```

Only problem is if you care about types which the last comparison tests.
If you care about types, you will have to loop.

```
function checkArrays( arrA, arrB ){

    //check if lengths are different
    if(arrA.length !== arrB.length) return false;

    //slice so we do not effect the orginal
    //sort makes sure they are in order
    var cA = arrA.slice().sort(); 
    var cB = arrB.slice().sort();

    for(var i=0;i<cA.length;i++){
         if(cA[i]!==cB[i]) return false;
    }

    return true;

}

var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
var b = [5,4,3,2,1];
var c = [1,2,3,4];
var d = [1,2,3,4,6];
var e = ["1","2","3","4","5"];

console.log( checkArrays(a,b) );  //true
console.log( checkArrays(a,c) );  //false
console.log( checkArrays(a,d) );  //false
console.log( checkArrays(a,e) );  //false
```

Answer (score 1):

I interpret your question is actually asking "*are these two structures actually equivalent*" rather than asking the more generic question "*how do I write code to compare two arrays*".

The simple answer is that (with the possible exception of an incorrect two-level nesting) the two arrays are *structurally* the same.  However for some reason one of the arrays is reversed.

How did you copy them?  The simplest way is just this:

```
var copy = [];
for (var i = 0; i < orig.length; ++i) {
    copy.push(orig[i]);
}
```

or even more trivially:

```
var copy = [].concat(orig);
```

If instead you used the following (incorrect) code:

```
for (var i in orig) {
    copy.push(orig[i]);
}
```

then the enumeration order is not guaranteed, which may be why you've ended up with a reversed array.